# Set a custom subclass of UINavigationBar in UINavigationController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Does anyone know how can I use my custom subclass of `UINavigationBar` if I instantiate `UINavigationController` programmatically (without IB)?

Drag a `UINavigationController` in IB show me an under Navigation Bar and using Identity Inspectory I can change class type and set my own subclass of `UINavigationBar` but programmatically I can't, `navigationBar` property of Navigation Controller is readonly...

What should I do to customize the navigation bar programmatically? Is IB more "powerful" than "code"? I believed all that can be done in IB could be done also programmatically.

Comment: did you have any luck finding a solution elsewhere?

Comment: do you get any answer about it?

Answer (score 89):

You don't need to muck with the XIB simply use KVC.

```
[self.navigationController setValue:[[[CustomNavBar alloc]init] autorelease] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
```

Comment: This solution works like a charm (at least on iOS 5.1). All the other solutions seem like way more work. Still looking for the downside.

Comment: how did you find this key path @"navigationBar" for navigation controller. can you share this

Comment: Are you sure this won't result in App rejection? I didn't see this documented anywhere actually.

Comment: Thanks! Works great in iOS 6 beta 3 too! @BaniUppal KVC is certainly documented, we're just using it with a key that is a bit difficult to find. I think that is the main point.

Comment: @Developer I think he may have used something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780897/how-do-i-find-all-the-property-keys-of-a-kvc-compliant-objective-c-object), but that's only a guess.

Comment: Works in iOS 7. What a great hack. I wonder why they don't just make UINavigationBar method read-write.

Comment: Tanks! This is a perfect solution for me =)

Comment: Works in iOS 8.3 also :)

Answer (score 67):

Since iOS5, apple provides a method to do this directly. [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
UINavigationController *navigationController= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithNavigationBarClass:[CustomNavBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
[navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:yourRootViewController]];
```

Comment: @nonamelive Actually not, added in iOS6: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/index.html

Comment: Yes, it's added in iOS 6, but it's also supported in iOS 5. An Apple engineer mentioned that in WWDC 2012 Session 216.

Answer (score 37):

As of iOS 4, you can use the `UINib` class to help solve this issue.

1. Create your custom `UINavigationBar` subclass.
2. Create an empty xib, add a `UINavigationController` as the single
   object.
3. Set the class for the `UINavigationController`'s `UINavigationBar` to your custom subclass.
4. Set your root view controller via one of these methods:

   - `[navController setViewcontrollers[NSArray arrayWithObject:myRootVC]];`
   - `[navController pushViewController:myRootVC];`

In code:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCustomXib" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = 
             [[nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now you've got a `UINavigationController` with your custom `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: Except then how do you set the rootViewController?

Comment: you use [navcontroller setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:<YOUR_ROOT_CONTROLLER>]]

Comment: sorry, you use you use [navcontroller pushViewController:<YOUR_ROOT_CONTROLLER> animated:NO]

Comment: IMHO this is the least "hackish" way here of making this sometimes-unavoidable hack.

Comment: Actually, one odd problem. When I do this the navigationItem of the new navigationController is not being set to the navigationItem property assigned to the viewController that I am pushing onto the (empty) stack.

Answer (score 26):

As far as I can tell, sometimes it is indeed necessary to subclass UINavigationBar, to do some nonstandard restyling.  It's sometimes possible to avoid having to do so by using [categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940290/best-point-to-overwrite-the-navigationbar-property-of-navigationcontroller), but not always.

Currently, as far as I know, the *only* way to set a custom UINavigationBar within a UIViewController is via IB (that is, via an archive) - it probably shouldn't be that way, but for now, we gotta live with it.

This is often fine, but sometimes using IB isn't really feasible.

So, I saw three options:

1. Subclass UINavigationBar and hook it all up in IB, then muck about loading up the nib each time I wanted a UINavigationController,
2. Use [method replacement](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html) within a category to change the behaviour of UINavigationBar, rather than subclassing, or
3. Subclass UINavigationBar and do a little mucking about with archiving/unarchiving the UINavigationController.

Option 1 was unfeasible (or at least too annoying) for me in this case, as I needed to create the UINavigationController programmatically, 2 is a little dangerous and more of a last-resort option in my opinion, so I chose option 3.

My approach was to create a 'template' archive of a UINavigationController, and unarchive that, returning it in `initWithRootViewController`.

Here's how:

In IB, I created a UINavigationController with the appropriate class set for the UINavigationBar.

Then, I took the existing controller, and saved an archived copy of it using `+[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:]`.  I just did this within the app delegate, in the simulator.

I then used the 'xxd' utility with the -i flag, to generate c code from the saved file, to embed the archived version in my subclass (`xxd -i path/to/file`).

Within `initWithRootViewController` I unarchive that template, and set self to the result of the unarchive:

```
// This is the data from [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:controller], where
// controller is a CTNavigationController with navigation bar class set to CTNavigationBar,
// from IB.  This c code was created using 'xxd -i'
static unsigned char archived_controller[] = {
    0x62, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x30, 0x30, 0xd4, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03,
    ...
};
static unsigned int archived_controller_len = 682;

...

- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {
     // Replace with unarchived view controller, necessary for the custom navigation bar
     [self release];
     self = (CTNavigationController*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:archived_controller length:archived_controller_len]];
     [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:rootViewController]];
     return [self retain];
}
```

Then, I can just grab a new instance of my UIViewController subclass which has the custom navigation bar set:

```
UIViewController *modalViewController = [[[CTNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTableViewController] autorelease];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

This gives me a modal UITableViewController with a navigation bar and toolbar all set up, and with the custom navigation bar class in place.  I didn't need to do any slightly-nasty method replacement, and I don't have to muck about with nibs when I really just want to work programmatically.

I would like to see the equivalent of `+layerClass` within UINavigationController - `+navigationBarClass` - but for now, this works.

Answer (score 5):

I use "option 1"

Create a nib-file with only the UINavigationController in it. And set the UINavigationBar Class to my custom Class.

```
self.navigationController = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"navigationbar" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

[navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: so the appropriate name of the nib-file would be loadNibNamed:@"navigationController ? You are actually getting the entire navigationController from the nib and not only the bar. Right ?

Comment: this does work for me, but when i click on any option in my tableview i lose the back button.

Answer (score 5):

Michael's solution works, but you can avoid NSKeyedArchiver and 'xxd' utility. Simply Subclass UINavigationController and override `initWithRootViewController`, loading your custom NavigationController NIB directly:

```
- (id) initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    [self release];
    self = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CTNavigationController" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] retain];  
    [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:rootViewController]];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Using `object_SetClass()` no longer works as if iOS5 GM. An alternate solution has been added below.

Use NSKeyedUnarchiver to manually set the unarchive class for the nav bar.

```
   MyViewController *controller = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
   NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:controller]] autorelease];
   [unarchiver setClass:[MyNavigationBar class] forClassName:@"UINavigationBar"];
   controller = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"root"];
```

---

**Note: This original solution only works pre-iOS5:**

There is a great solution, which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672229/subclass-uinavigationbar-and-add-it-to-uinavigationcontroller-programmatically-i/7677915#7677915) -- inject navBar subclass directly into your view the `UINavigationController`:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    object_setClass(self.navigationController.navigationBar, [MyNavBar class]);
    // the rest of your viewDidLoad code
}
```

Comment: As I indicated in the previous answer you posted this on -- the gold master of iOS5 broke this. There are other options available though, so I'll edit with an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

One scenario I've found that we need to use subclass rather than category is to set navigationbar backgroundcolor with pattern image, because in iOS5 overwriting drawRect using category does not work any more. If you want to support ios3.1-5.0, the only way you can do is to subclass navigationbar.

Answer (score 1):

These category methods are dangerous and not for novices. Also the complication with iOS4 and iOS5 being different, makes this an area that can cause bugs for many people. Here is a simple subclass that I use that supports iOS4.0 ~ iOS6.0 and is very simply.

**.h**

```
@interface XXXNavigatioNBar : UINavigationBar
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "XXXNavigationBar.h"

#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation XXXNavigationBar

- (void) didMoveToSuperview {
    if( [self respondsToSelector: @selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) {
        //iOS5.0 and above has a system defined method -> use it
        [self setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"nav-bar"]
                   forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else {
        //iOS4.0 requires us to override drawRect:. BUT!!
        //If you override drawRect: on iOS5.0 the system default will break,
        //so we dynamically add this method if required
        IMP implementation = class_getMethodImplementation([self class], @selector(iOS4drawRect:));
        class_addMethod([self class], @selector(drawRect:), implementation, "v@:{name=CGRect}");
    }
}

- (void)iOS4drawRect: (CGRect) rect {
    UIImage* bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-blue"];
    [bg drawInRect: rect];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's **not recommended** to subclass the `UINavigationBar` class. The preferred way to customizing the navigation bar is to set it's properties to make it appear as you wish and use custom views inside UIBarButtonItems along with a delegate to get the desired behavior.

What are you trying to do that needs subclassing?

Also, I don't think IB is actually replacing the navigation bar. I'm pretty sure it's simply not displaying the default one and has your custom nav bar as a subview. If you call UINavigationController.navigationBar, do you get an instance of your bar?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks. I know is not the better way to subclass UINavigationBar but I would like setup a background image overriding drawRect: method.

The problem is that using IB I can change the class of Navigation Bar in a UINavigationController but programmatically I can't.

And yes, IB is actually replacing the navigation bar:

NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.navigationBar);

<CustomNavigationBar: 0x1806160; baseClass = UINavigationBar; frame = (0 20; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1806da0>>

Comment: I'm also using this same technique, and it continues to work in iOS5 (unlike the UINavigationBar Category technique.)

Answer (score 0):

Further to obb64's comment, I ended up using his trick with `setViewControllers:animated:` to set the controller as the `rootController` for the `navigationController` loaded from the nib.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
- (void) presentModalViewControllerForClass: (Class) a_class {
  UINavigationController *navController = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"CustomNavBar" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

  LoginSignupBaseViewController *controller = [[a_class alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
  controller.navigationController = navController;
  [navController setViewControllers: A(controller) animated: NO];

  [self presentModalViewController: navController animated: YES];

  [controller release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subclass navBar just to change background image - there is no need to in iOS 5.
There will be method like this one **setBackgroundImage**

Comment: you need to use `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`as described here:http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html