# Best point to overwrite the navigationBar property of navigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, subclassing

I'm overwriting `UINavigationController` to replace the default `navigationBar` property with an instance of my own subclass of `UINavigationBar`. So I tried something like

```
_navigationBar = [[SBNavigationBar alloc] init];
```

in my `-initWithRootViewController:`. But that didn't work out as I expected it. There's still the default `navigationBar` being displayed.

So what's the best point to overwrite the `navigationBar`?

Thanks in advance
–f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html, you'll see that the **navigationBar** property is **read-only**.

To have a custom `navigationBar` you can use Categories for example. You will find many questions answering this here on **stackoverflow**.

One simple version is putting an image in **drawRect:** like so...

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Custom)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bg_toolbar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```