# Custom UINavigationController UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Basically I want a custom `UINavigationBar`. I don't want it to be "translucent" or anything, like the pictures app.

I basically want to completely remove it, but I still want to be able to add back buttons and such when navigation controllers are pushed, and I want the views (EG: `UITableViewController`) to be pushed down below it.

Like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve this at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (background)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

basically, its not completely see through - its a visual lie. The only way to do it realistically is to override `UINavigationBar`'s `drawRect:` method, as shown above.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to [override methods from a category](http://thaesofereode.info/clocFAQ/#categories-multiple).

Comment: err... is there another way to do it mr Justin?

Comment: Sorry, I should have offered this alternative instead of just critiquing an old post: You can override `drawRect:` in a proper subclass of `UINavigationBar` and then set it as the class of your `UINavigationController`'s nav bar. However, the only "official" way to set this class is through a XIB.

Comment: Ah fair enough. There's no way to change the class of the UINavigationController's nav bar programatically?

Comment: Not through official APIs, no, but [workarounds exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080665).

Answer (score 5):

To see through the `UINavigationBar`, if you choose to have one, just:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=YES;
```

You'll have to change the tint/color to match the background if you want it to appear like the image you posted.

Comment: That just makes it semi-transparent... its ok, I found another way of doing it... see my answer

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your `AppDelegate` subclass `UINavigationBar` as below:

```
@interface CustomNavBar : UINavigationBar

@end

@implementation CustomNavBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

and then in the `AppDelegate` do this magic:

```
//Set custom NavigationBar
[self.navController setValue:[[CustomNavBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
//Set tint to match bar.png
self.navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.93 green:0.43 blue:0 alpha:1];
//Set font for NavigationBar
[self.navController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Comfortaa-Bold" size:20], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
```

That should give you a lot more control over `UINavigationController` look & feel.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, could be the `UINavigationBar` is there and color matches the `UIView` background or, there is no `UINavigationBar`, just a view with custom buttons and `UILabel` on top. Pick an approach and code it, or ask the question again with more specifics.

Comment: I don't know how to specify more. I want a see-through navigation bar. Am I just going to have to create my own navigation bar style element? In which case - how do I know if I'm on the root view controller? If I'm not on the root view controller I can just add a "back" button to the view can't I?