# Persistent header in app with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, header, uinavigationcontroller

I have a nice iPhone app built that uses a UINavigationController to navigate through a series of tableviews.  I now want to add a persistent banner at the top of all of my views, either above the navigation bar or just below it.  I do not want it to scroll with the tableview, so I do not want to make it a custom first row.

Any ideas on the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did to achieve this was to make a new UIView for each of the views that I needed the banner on, and placed the banner in there, and the table or other view below the banner.  This doesn't keep the banner there persistently through the transitions which is what I really wanted, but I was able to get a non-scrolling header above my tables.

**EDIT:**
The "correct" way to do this now would be to have a root view controller that consists of your header, and a container view, and then all of the navigation and content goes inside your container view.  Although this does require ios6+

Comment: I have the same problem: the need to show a persistent view on every screen. Your solution however isn't persistent at all, not sure why you marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @mixedCase I marked it as accepted because it was what I used to resolve the problem.  Like I said in the answer originally the banner does move with the view, however I just had each view contain the banner.  I did edit the answer for a more up to date solution

Comment: @DanF how did you handle the navigation inside the container? i have the same issue but am unsure of how to best change container child view from within itself

Answer (score 1):

You could customize your navigation bar so that it displays the "classical" bar and then, above or below it, it draws your specific content. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042108/custom-uinavigationcontroller-uinavigationbar) for more detail.