# How do I change the background of a UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, tabbar

I'd like to change the background of my UINavigationBar to a `[UIColor colorWithImage:]`, but it isn't working. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Once I've created my subclass, where do I set the UINavigationController to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `tintColor` property to change the *colour* of a `UINavigationBar`, but to set an image as the background you'll have to provide your own `UINavigationBar` subclass and override the `drawRect:` method, for example:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code 
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"background-image.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 
                               0, 
                               self.frame.size.width, 
                               self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

If you use Interface Builder to build your UI then to use the custom navigation bar, just select the UINavigationBar element in Interface Builder, open the Inspector and in the Identity tab specify your UINavigationBar subclass in the class field, like so:

[image: Example screenshot showing custom UINavigationBar subclass]

Comment: Now how do I set the UINavigationBar to show inside of the UINavigationController?

Comment: Good question - answer amended accordingly.

Comment: Is this possible purely in code? Also, does this break HIG at all?

Comment: I don't believe it breaks HIG. I have apps on the App Store that use this.

Comment: It looks as though setting it in code isn't possible, unless you use  UINavigationController's undocumented `setNavigationBar:` method, which works but is likely to get your app rejected from the App Store. You can use Denis Hennessy's category solution (one of the other answers here) to achieve this purely in code. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869331/set-programmatically-a-custom-subclass-of-uinavigationbar-in-uinavigationcontroll) has some other suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

To have an image in the navigation bar, you have to draw it yourself, which actually isn't that hard. Save this as `UINavigationBar+CustomBackground.m` (it adds a custom category to UINavigationBar):

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavMain.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Using a category would irrevocably change the background of *all* navigation bars.  You're better off using a subclass.

Comment: we used this method until we wanted different navigation bars on different view controllers. Then this method unfortunately fails

Comment: Actually folks, you may be able to do some class detection and behave differently based on the class. You still have to reimplement the default behaviors though.