# UINavigationBar tintColor

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

Does the tint color have to be a very simple, solid UIColor for a UINavigationBar?

I have a color made from a pattern, and I'm trying to use that. Is this not possible? Is there any way to do it? The bar just came out black.

```
   UIColor* tmpColor = [ [UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"best.png"]];    
   [theBar setTintColor:tmpColor];
```

Comment: I really don't think it's possible.

Comment: It **will** be possible in iOS5

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319112/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-a-uinavigationbar

Comment: @Kashiv iOS 5 is under NDA: you may not yet say that here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is that it is not possible in the current iOS version.

Comment: Not a helpful answer-- "current iOS version" isn't a very future-proof term.