# Issues with changing UINavigationBar background when presenting modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I am using  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319112/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-a-uinavigationbar) method to change the backgrounds of my uiviewcontrollers. It generally works when I push a view controller.

However, if the viewcontroller is presented using

```
[self presentModalViewController:customViewController animated:YES];
```

then, this code doesnt work. Can anyone kindly suggest whats wrong ?

Code used:

To have an image in the navigation bar, you have to draw it yourself, which actually isn't that hard. Save this as UINavigationBar+CustomBackground.m (it adds a custom category to UINavigationBar):

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavMain.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried with:

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:customViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on iOS 5, then `drawRect:` is no longer called

You will need to either use the `UIAppearance` or subclass `UINavigationController` and use that to change to you image.

A tutorial for `UIAppearance` can be found [here](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=418)

(`drawRect:` will still work on versions below iOS 5)

Comment: My work around works perfect for view controllers that are pushed. For those that are presented modally, its causing this problem. Any clue why ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it is iOS 5 then it shouldn't be. Unless `setNeedsDisplay` is called. Although I don't know if that works.

Comment: i dont think so, but appreciate the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is it but have you tried

```
[self presentViewController:customViewController animated:YES completion:NULL]
```

And setting whatever modalViewStyle you deem appropriate for customViewController?  According to the [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), presentModalViewController is deprecated, so you may have better luck using the above message call (especially since you only seem to be having this issue with modal view controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]];
```

replace image name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a navigation controller, set the root controller and present it.

e.g.

UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *cntrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self presentModalViewController:cntrol animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

The method you is to set the navigation bar image in navigation controller.

But The new view controller you present is not using navigation method. Instead, you use Modal view Controller.

I have two solution for you:

--- 1 -----

still use Modal View Controller, just add that image on the top of new view controller.

```
[self.view addSubview:theImage];
```

---- 2 -----

use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:customViewController animated:YES];
```

instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:customViewController animated:YES];
```

In this case, you are using navigation.

I will suggest the second one.