# UINavigationBar : customized button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I want to make a navigation bar looking like BRED's application :

[image: BRED's main view]

But I don't know how to remove the border and the bottom of the bar button.

Thank you for your advices

Comment: That is a really ugly navigation bar. Please don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If iOS 5 or greater check out the [UIAppearance API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Otherwise, there are a bunch of resources on SO to customize the nab bar, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672229/how-to-subclass-uinavigationbar-for-a-uinavigationcontroller-programatically). There is no way to just remove the border, you will have to create it from scratch.