# correct way of using UINavigationController's initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:

Tags: ios

From the apple docs I understand that a UiNavigationController can be instantiated with another Uinavigationbar using initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass: method. How does one correctly do this via a custom UiNavigationBar subclass and IB?

Comment: And there's this issue!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286166

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use it like this to initialize the navigation controller,

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CustomNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
```

Here `CustomNavigationBar` is the custom class created by subclassing `UINavigationBar`. You can set the viewcontrollers by using the `setViewControllers` property of UINavigationController.

If you want to do this in IB, try this. Select navigation bar from objects and in the identity inspector, select the custom class for navigationbar.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In Interface Builder, you click on the navigation bar inside the navigation controller. Inspect it on the right panel, and change the custom class from `UINavigationBar` to your custom subclass.

In code, make sure you have imported your header file for the navigation bar subclass and write something similar to the following.

```
// This code assumes `MyCustomNavigationBar` is the name of your custom subclass, and that `viewController` is a UIViewController object created earlier.

// To create the containing navigation controller
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[MyCustomNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:[UIToolbar class]];

// To set the root view controller in the navigation controller
navigationController.viewControllers = @[viewController];
```

The code above informs UIKit to create a `UINavigationController` with navigation bars of subclass `MyCustomNavigationBar`. Then, it sets the root view controller to the object stored in the variable `viewController`.

Answer (score 2):

Just mashing up Benjamin Mayo's answer here for your general subclass

```
- (UINavigationController *)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController  navigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass {
    self = [super initWithNavigationBarClass:navigationBarClass toolbarClass:UIToolbar.class];
    if (self) {
        self.viewControllers = @[rootViewController];
    }
    return self;
}
```