# Confusion about initWithNavigationBarClass - how to use (new instanceType method)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, instancetype

This works great:

```
UINavigationController *nc =
    [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithNavigationBarClass:[GTScrollNavigationBar class]
    toolbarClass:[UIToolbar class]];
nc.viewControllers = @[firstPage];
self.window.rootViewController = nc;
```

but this does ***not*** work:

```
UINavigationController *nc =
    [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithNavigationBarClass:[GTScrollNavigationBar class]
    toolbarClass:[UIToolbar class]];
self.window.rootViewController = nc;
self.window.rootViewController.viewControllers = @[firstPage]; // ERROR
```

how can it be?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.window.rootViewController.viewControllers = @[firstPage];
```

does not compile because the `rootViewController` property of `UIWindow` is declared
as a (generic) `UIViewController` (which does not have a `viewControllers` property), and not as a `UINavigationController`.

The compiler does not "know" that the root view controller is actually a navigation
controller in your case.

So either you proceed as in your first code block, or you have to add an explicit cast:

```
((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController).viewControllers = @[firstPage];
```