# How do I resize height of UINavigationBar while allowing to set root view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, resize, uinavigationbar

I want to resize height of `UINavigationBar` I came across few questions previously asked here, but I believe this is quite different then those.

Found that, I've to make subclass of `UINavigationBar` and where I should update height of it. But then to use that subclassed navigation bar I've to use below method of `UINavigationController`.

Here it is:

```
- (id) initWithNavigationBarClass:(nullable Class)navigationBarClass 
toolbarClass:(nullable Class)toolbarClass;
```

if I used this to set my subclassed navigation bar, then how do I set its `rootViewController` using below method:

```
- (id) initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;
```

Is there any other way that, I can achieve my goal of resized navigationbar height and also I should set a root view controller to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing `UINavigationBar` do the trick !

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BaseNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@end

@implementation BaseNavigationBar
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {return CGSizeMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width, 24.f);}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) they say that the property `viewControllers`returns an array that at index 0 contains the root view controller.
I think that if you pass at this property an array of VCs the object at index zero will be taken as the root. Or just a one element array.