# NavigationController with sticky view at top

Tags: ios, swift

I have a navigation controller with its root view controller, I need to add a fixed/ sticky view at the top of the root view controller, so that only the content below it navigates whenever I use pushViewController or popViewController, is that possible?

Look at the image below, I want the red area to be fixed/sticky a.k.a doesn't navigate or move when I push or pop, only the blue area to navigate

[image]

P.S: The containerView won't work here as it acts as normal view, and adds its sub view controller's view to it.

Comment: Add a containerView in the place of blue view, and set your changing viewController  into the containerView

Comment: Please check edited version

Comment: If you have the stomach for it, you could subclass `UINavigationController` - but it's tricky - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672229/how-to-subclass-uinavigationbar-for-a-uinavigationcontroller-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Add a container View to add as child view controller for your navigation and set `navigationBar` as hidden. Now you can add the above view with 44 height as a sticky one for all View controllers. 
If you want a way to communicate between child view controllers under navagtion with the parent I would suggest `NSNotification` observer or a Delegation to be confirmed by all child VC or by a subclass of `UINavigationController`.
This is a sytematic way.

Other dummy way is to add a view to the `window` and set the `view.layer.zPosition` if you want it below or above any other view.

Comment: No, I don't know you know it when you add childVC you specically call `addChildViewController()` and view in a separate place. An we know controller always know the view using `self.view`. It works you need to figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Container View and show/hide other views