# UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics: Not Working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I just switched over to iOS 5 and everything appears to be working in my application aside from the custom navigation bar.  I looked around and followed everybody's suggestion of calling the new methods setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics: however it doesn't appear to work.  This is the code I've tried to place both within the app delegate and within the viewDidLoad method of some of the view controllers:

```
UINavigationBar *nb = [[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
if( [nb respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] )
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarBackground.png"];
    [nb setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
[nb release];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.  If anybody has any suggestions at all, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To apply `image` to all your navigation bars, use the appearance proxy:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

For an individual bar:

```
// Assuming "self" is a view controller pushed on to a UINavigationController stack
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In your example, the background image won't change because `nb` isn't hooked up to anything.

Comment: Note that this will only work for devices running iOS 5. If you need to have backward compatibility to 4.x you will have to figure something else out.

Comment: on iOS 7 this appears to be doing some really weird tiling

Comment: @Odelya I re-did my background graphic to fit exactly, I think 320x64 off the top of my head

Comment: Yes, this makes strange tiling in the navigation bar. the image width is less than 320. I want it centered. any solution?

Comment: For all these methods, you need exactly 320x44/64 image. Otherwise iOS creates strange tiling!

Answer (score 4):

Answer by rob is correct but if application runs on iOS 4.3 or lower app will crash. So you can implement this like

```
if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) //iOS >=5.0
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar-Landscape.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];   

}
```

This will set image for both mode Landscape and Portrait

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The proper solution is this: if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) { //code }

Comment: @BorutTomazin: This does actually work, quite well! You could do a further test to see if [UINavigationBar appearance] responds to selector `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`, but this is the 'first stage' in testing that UINavigationBar first responds to the `appearance` method (iOS5 only).

Comment: Thanks sir, your code snippet was of great help to me. And thanks once again that because of you i have iOS development as my career. A vote up from me :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the navigation bar from a navigation controller. Right now you are just creating one and then it deallocs when you release it. You need to get the navigation controller for your view controller.

```
UINavigationController * navigationController = [self navigationController];
UINavigationBar * nb = [navigationController navigationBar];
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you want to apply the same to a toolbar, it is slightly different. Here's an example, building on Rob's answer:

```
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarDarkWoodGrain.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do something like use a UINavigationBar subclass? If you do this and override drawRect: on iOS5 and above, things will break.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869331/set-a-custom-subclass-of-uinavigationbar-in-uinavigationcontroller-programmatica/12669889#12669889) for a way to support both OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
UIView *parentViewLeft = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
parentViewLeft.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];    
} else {
    UIImageView* imgBG = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imgBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
    imgBG.frame = CGRectMake(-10,0, 330, 44);
    [parentViewLeft addSubview:imgBG];
}

UIBarButtonItem *customBarButtomLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:parentViewLeft];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarButtomLeft;
```