# Set a different background image for UINavigationBar in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, background-image

My app has several viewControllers and for some of them, I would like to use a different navigationbar background image when they are pushed onto the navigation stack.

For example, when my mainViewController loads up, I have this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"Setting toolbar for iOS 5+");
    UIImage * navbarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar01.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Likewise, when my other viewController is pushed onto the navigation stack, I am using the same code as above, except using a different UIImage (navbar02.png).

However, the navigation bar doesn't change from the first image that I set.  Is there any way to change the UINavigationBar background image when a new view appears?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link for similar question: [UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics: Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760819/uinavigationbar-setbackgroundimage-forbarmetrics-not-working)

The answer is to use this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

rather than the code you have used.

Answer (score 1):

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
//  NSLog(@"%f",version);
if (version >= 5.0) {
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
else
{
   // UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    NSString *barBgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NavBar" ofType:@"png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer setContents:(id)[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: barBgPath].CGImage];
}
```

its working successfully for me ... maybe it will help you.