# How can I change the UINavigationBar of a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController that I'm creating programatically:

```
 MessageTableViewController* homeStream = [[MessageTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageTableViewController" bundle:nil];
          homeStream.fetchHomeStream = YES;
          homeStream.title = @"Home";
          UINavigationController* navBarController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeStream];
          navBarController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hometab.png"];
          [homeStream release];
```

I have a custom UINavigationBar called STNavigationBar. How can I use STNavigationBar instead of the default UINavigationBar that is part of the UINavigationController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the iOS5 UIKit appearance proxy:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

No subclassing, or categories needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** for future readers, the answer below does not work anymore on iOS 5.

You can't just set it to the existing instance, because *UINavigationController* has a **readonly** property for *navigationBar*. And I don't think subclassing a UINavigationController is what you want.

I recon the best way to do this is to create a category that extends a UINavigationBar, as discussed [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/7944826#7944826).

Comment: I originally had it as a category which worked fine, but iOS5 breaks this functionality, and it is now bad practice to use categories to over-ride actual methods. So I decided to subclass it. It works when I set the navigation bar in IB, but I also need to set it programatically...

Comment: I was not aware of that. What about option no. 3 in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869331/set-programmatically-a-custom-subclass-of-uinavigationbar-in-uinavigationcontrol/3080665#3080665

Comment: Just posted an answer, I used iOS5 UIKit appearance proxy