# Custom drawRect: in UINavigationBar subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I want to subclass `UINavigationBar` so that I can do custom drawing in its `drawRect:`.

Here's my code:

**Navigation Controller (.h)**

```
@interface CORENavigationController : UINavigationController

@property (strong, nonatomic) CORENavigationBar *customNavigationBar;

@end
```

**Navigation Controller (.m)**

```
@implementation CORENavigationController

@synthesize customNavigationBar = _customNavigationBar;

- (UINavigationBar *)navigationBar {
    if (![self customNavigationBar]) {
        [self setCustomNavigationBar:[[CORENavigationBar alloc] init]];
    }
    return [self customNavigationBar];
}
```

**Navigation Bar (.h)**

```
@interface CORENavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@end
```

**Navigation Bar (.m)**

```
@implementation CORENavigationBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

The issue is that the navigation bar has no title, e.g. all I can see is just the standard blue background.

As soon as I remove the following method, the title is back there:

```
- (UINavigationBar *)navigationBar {
    if (![self customNavigationBar]) {
        [self setCustomNavigationBar:[[CORENavigationBar alloc] init]];
    }
    return [self customNavigationBar];
}
```

Why does the title disappear? I call the `super`'s `drawRect:` and do not change anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: question is unclear. "As soon as I remove this method" being which method? drawRect or the one after the colon? If it's `drawRect` then it's a very interesting question ;)

Comment: @Yar Fixed. It's the method that follows after the colon. Simply put, as soon as I don't override `navigationBar`, the title is back there. Hopefully it's clearer. Thanks for comment!

Comment: It's possible that the `navigationBar` method returns a concrete subclass of `UINavigationBar` or at the very least sets up the instance. Debug and see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a custom subclass of UINavigationBar in UINavigationController programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869331/set-a-custom-subclass-of-uinavigationbar-in-uinavigationcontroller-programmatica)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! Here's the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9610801/1306956

In this case, it'd be:

```
[navigationController setValue:[[CORENavigationBar alloc] init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
```

Tested on iOS 5.1.1 (9B206). Works like a charm.