# Setting UINavigationBar Subclass in UINavigationController subclass

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, uinavigationbar, subclass

I have a subclass of `UINavigationBar` and I want to make a subclass of `UINavigationController` that uses this `UINavigationBar` subclass. I know how to set the default `UINavigationController` to use a custom Navigation Bar

`let navController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: CustomNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)`

however I want to be able to create a custom `UINavigationController` (programatically) that already sets my custom navigation bar as its navigation bar class. I have seen how to do it at this link but it seems a bit dated (2012) and 'hacky AF' - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9610801/2654425. I know how to do it in 'Storyboard' by setting the navigation bar class of the `UINavigationController` but I would like this to be done programmatically in my Custom UINavigation Controller.

Here is a basic `UINavigationBar` and `UINavigationController` Subclass:

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!


    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }


}

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Im not sure where to set the custom navigation bar. Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: try to add in viewDidLayoutSubViews Method.

Answer (score 1):

You should set when you instantiate your UINavigationController subclass. Specifically, UINavigationController.init(navigationBarClass: AnyClass?, toolbarClass: AnyClass?). See [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621866-init) in Apple's documentation.