# How can I iterate over a class keys in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How can I iterate over an instance properties in objective-C ?

I need to get all the properties values without having to specify them.

This is the only solution I've found so far, but I was wondering if it could be done with less code: [Get an object properties list in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754824/get-an-object-attributes-list-in-objective-c)

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "class keys"?

Comment: I mean the properties, and I used the term "key" in the context of Key-Value Coding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/780897/491980

Comment: And this link has the revised code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754824/get-an-object-attributes-list-in-objective-c/4008326#4008326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : @EmptyStack has the right idea - follow his link in the comments on the question :)

---

Take a look at these methods : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyPropertyList

They let you (amongst other things) find all the properties that a class implements. You can then run through that array of properties and call `performSelector:` for each property you are interested in.