# NSUserDefault not storing value

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Hello I am saving values when user successfully login.

```
case 200:
           let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                        prefs.setObject(email, forKey: "EMAIL")
                        prefs.setObject(result["User"]!["profile_image"], forKey: "PROFILEIMAGE")
                        prefs.setObject(result["User"]!["first_name"], forKey: "FIRSTNAME")
                        prefs.setObject(result["User"]!["last_name"], forKey: "LASTNAME")
                        prefs.setObject(result["User"]!["Country"], forKey: "COUNTRY")
                        prefs.setObject(result["User"]!["user_id"], forKey: "USERID")

                        prefs.setObject(result["User"]!["session_token"], forKey: "SESSIONTOKEN")
                        prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")

                        prefs.synchronize()


                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            let nav : SWRevealViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("swrevealviewcontroller") as! SWRevealViewController
                            self.navigationController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                            })                            
                        })


                        break;
```

I am getting the `PROFILEIMAGE` value nil when I try to  get the value like this

```
let userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        print("userdefault is \(userDefaults.stringForKey("PROFILEIMAGE"))")
```

So In order to check all the keys and values stored in the phone I did this

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation())
```

I checked the console and I don't find `COUNTRY` and `PROFILEIMAGE` key and values in console

Please help me what I am doing wrong here

Comment: in this place `stringForKey` use `valueForKey` or `ObjectForkey` and try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSUserDefaults Unreliable in iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917106/nsuserdefaults-unreliable-in-ios-8)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No luck :(

Comment: what type of object, you are dealing with ? <result["User"]!["profile_image"]>

Comment: @KumarKL   I am storing iMAGE URL in it

Comment: Can u just try to print **result["User"]!["profile_image"]** before store to the user defaults

Comment: confirm once `result["User"]!["profile_image"]` contains data or not

Comment: oh yeah my mistake.. the data was not coming here. I am really sorry for taking your guys time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the data(string value) is not nil.

```
if let url: String = result["User"]!["profile_image"] {
    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    prefs.setObject(result["User"]!["profile_image"], forKey: "PROFILEIMAGE")
   prefs.synchronize()
}
```

And retrive :

```
let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let storedURL: String = prefs.objectForKey(PROFILEIMAGE) as? String{
// Do your stuff

}
```

Comment: You answer is correct but if I may be pedantic you don't have to call synchronize anymore since iOS 8.