# Linker error , Undefined symbols: "_getPropertyType" when using Objective-C Runtime Reference

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, linker

I was trying to get the property name with following codes and hit the linker error, **Undefined symbols:  "_getPropertyType"**

```
unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
for(i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    const char *propName = property_getName(property);
    if(propName) {
        const char *propType = getPropertyType(property);
        NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName];
        NSString *propertyType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propType];
        }
    }
 }
```

I already import #import "objc/runtime.h", so is there any linker flag I need to turn on ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling getPropertyType()? What else do you do in that code?

Comment: Yes I am calling getPropertyType(). I have pasted all the codes  related to runtime reference again. It is quite simple, right? I guess I must miss something (maybe even stupid :$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the linker told you, there’s no `getPropertyType()` function exported by the Objective-C runtime API. In fact, the compiler should’ve warned you before the linker since there’s no corresponding declaration.

The runtime API does export a function called `property_getAttributes` that returns a [C string describing the property type](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW6). This is described in the [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html) document. You need to parse that string in order to obtain whichever information you want.

There’s another [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754824/get-an-object-attributes-list-in-objective-c) in which one answer contains the definition of a `getPropertyType()` function that parses the string returned by `property_getAttributes()`. It might be what you’re looking for. In fact, your code looks quite similar to the code in the other answer.

Comment: Yes indeed like you said, compiler did not give me any warning so I was confused what was going on here and did not realize that just means there’s no getPropertyType() function exported by the Objective-C runtime API. Thanks! And thanks for the link, I did copy my codes from somewhere (not from that link though)

Comment: @Qiulang Just curious: any particular reason why you’ve chosen Jonathan’s answer over mine?

Comment: No I did not choose his answer over yours. I did not even realize I chose his answer over yours. Of course your answer was more complete and I chose your (by checked it). Then I found both of you answered it again (or whatever that meant because your names both showed up at the second answer) so I checked it again.

Comment: Now since I learned I can only check one, I chose your answer of course.

Comment: @Qiulang Aha!, I thought that might have been the case. My name appears in his answer because I’ve edited it (corrected ABI to API). Cheers!

Comment: So you can edit others' answer ? That is weird,I did not realize in stackoverflow you can do that. Thanks for answering my question again.

Comment: @Qiulang Yes, Stack Overflow is collaboratively edited as explained in [the FAQ, question ‘Other people can edit my stuff?!’](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Depending on the reputation, edits can be automatically applied or stay in a pending state awaiting for other people to approve them.

Answer (score 0):

`getPropertyType()` isn't part of the Objective-C API. (i.e. the function doesn't exist in libobjc.)