# Objective-C: How to get the value of a `objc_property_t` property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I use the following code to iterate through all the properties of an object. I successfully retrieve the `property name` as `char` but I have no idea how to get the `property value` which is of `id` type. Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

```
objc_property_t *allProperties = class_copyPropertyList([currentObject class], &allPropertyCount);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < allPropertyCount; i++) {

      objc_property_t property = allProperties[i];
      const char * propertyName = property_getName(property);

}
```

========================================================================================

EDIT: Thank you all for the great comments and answers. Some of you asked why do I need this. Well, here is the reason:

I have several objects of the same class. Let's say the class is `Person` and its instances are Mary, John and David. The properties of each object are set as follows:

```
mary.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:20];
john.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:45];
david.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:20];

mary.gender = @"female";
john.gender = @"male";
david.gender = @"male";
```

My purpose is to find a **generic** way to group the objects based on a given property name Eg. this will create 2 groups [david and mary] and [john]:

```
[self groupBaseDataObjects:self.persons withPropertyName:"age"];
```

and this:

```
[self groupBaseDataObjects:self.persons withPropertyName:"gender"];
```

will also create 2 groups [john and david] and [mary]

Comment: This related question has what you need: [object attribute list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754824/get-an-object-attributes-list-in-objective-c)

Comment: `property_getName` returns the name of the property (eg for an object with a property like this `obj.prop` it will return "prop")

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Down this path generally lies madness (save for in a handful of outlying esoteric situations that are pretty much crazy town, but still possible).

Comment: Please see the updated description for the idea behind this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK -- there appears to be no need to do any funky runtime gymnastics to solve your problem (don't get me wrong -- funky runtime gymnastics can be fun.... but it is probably just a waste of time here).

To restate the question:

> You have a single class (MyClass) with many instances of that class.  The class
>   provides several attributes with instances of the class having many
>   different values for that attribute.   You have a collection of
>   instances and you want to easily grab a collection of multiple subsets
>   where the objects in each subset have the same value for a particular
>   attribute.

To that end, I'd just loop over the original question and do something like (this code has never seen a compiler;  it'll probably not compile):

```
// implement this on MyClass
+ (NSDictionary*)subdivideArrayOfMyClass:(NSArray*) aCollection byAttribute:(NSString*) anAttribute
{
    NSMutableDictionary *collector = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (MyClass *anObject in aCollection) {
        id value = [anObject valueForKey: anAttribute];
        // you'd have to special case for nil here if you wanted.
        NSMutableArray *sameValueCollector = [collector objectForKey: value];
        if (!sameValueCollector) {
             sameValueCollector = [NSMutableArray array];
             [collector setObject: sameValueCollector forKey:value];
        }

        [sameValueCollector addObject:anObject];
    }
    return collector; // no need to turn it into an immutable dict
}
```

This does assume that all the values are safe for use as keys in a dictionary.   That would be true for the examples you gave.

If you need all objects with a single value, you could do valueForKey: on the array.  If you wanted, you could do some funky set arithmetic to sub-divide the objects.  However, that'll likely incur multiple passes over the collection whereas the above does the work with one pass (though a potentially large quantity of hash lookups in the collector).  Go with the straightforward until performance analysis indicates that it is too slow.

Comment: Ok, so basically you can access `mary.age`  like this: `[mary valueForKey: @"age"];`? That's awesome, didn't knew that...

Comment: Yup;   Do a search for **Key Value Coding**.

Comment: OK, I've tested the code and indeed it works with `NSObjects` but for custom objects I get `-[Person objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f41730` I'll do some more digging, worst case scenario I'll implement the `objectForKey` method in Person class myself. Anyway is better than runtime gymnastics :D

Comment: Yup -- been there done exactly that... scratchscratchscratchDERP. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `valueForKey:`.

```
id object = [customObject valueForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:propertyName]];
```

You can use `isEqual:` to compare. You will get an `NSNumber` or `NSValue` where appropriate. Read the KVC guide for more.

**Earlier Answer**

<strike>Since the getter method will match the property name, you can generate the selector of the property name and call `performSelector` on the object.</strike>

```
[customObject performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithUTF8String:propertyName])];
```

Comment: Cool. If you find `NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithUTF8String:propertyName])` verbose, you should be able to replace it with `sel_getUid(propertyName)`.

Comment: what about `@property(getter=boogerHead) BOOL isNasty;`?

Comment: @mindnoise This is far from being a proper answer. You might want to unmark it as the answer. The problem is clearly indicated indicated in the example above. @bbum You are right. I overlooked the `getter` part but even if we figure it out using the attributes provided by `property_getAttributes` function it is not as trivial as using `performSelector` which is not the right for primitives i.e. `BOOL`. We will have to make the proper calls based on the return type. Do you know of a better way to approach this?

Comment: I see your point bbum, however, i can control the object's properties and the way they are declared and will avoid that situation.

Comment: @deepak this serves well my purpose (the properties are never primitives and I don't use the 'getter' part) However, i'll uncheck the answer as being correct to see if someone can come up with a better way to do it. Personally I prefer to do it this way if I can control the object's property, it's simpler than parsing 'property_getAttributes'

Comment: @mindnoise Please do. However, I would also like to know what is the idea behind doing this. Probably there is a better approach there.