# How to get navController from AppDelegate.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I am wondering, that how to get navController from `AppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` in the iPhone programming. e.g., in other viewController where we reference to the AppDelegate.

In the applicationDelegate.h we have:

```
UINavigationController *navController;
```

And the following in applicationDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

   [window addSubview: navController.view];
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Is there anyway to get the navController from the mainWindow:

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [appDelegate window];
```

Comment: Why don't you make the nav controller a property of your app delegate?

Comment: I need to get the information about the navController only by the mainWindow (UIWindow *mainWindow = [appDelegate window]), is taht possible.

Comment: I suppose no. But why can't you use the app delegate, really?

Comment: looks like i need to use the Obj-C Runtime Library like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754824/get-an-object-attributes-list-in-objective-c

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If this other UIViewController is contained in the UINavigationController, you can simply call:

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
```

from the UIViewController.

Otherwise, you can set UINavigationController as a property in the AppDelegate.

```
// AppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navController;
```

Then access `appDelegate.navController`.

Or, you can set the UINavigationController as window's rootViewController:

```
[window setRootViewController:navController];
```

And call from anywhere:

```
UINavigationController *navController = window.rootViewController;
```

Comment: Very instructive! Thank you! One question though: if you're going to access the navController through `window`, don't you have to get access through the UIApplication? Is there perhaps a shorter way?

Comment: You can get to the window from any UIView with the `window` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the navController a property

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UINavigationController *navController;
```

Then just access it from your appdelegate

```
appDelegate.Controller
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `navController` as a property of your delegate class. sample below:

In applicationDelegate.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
```

In applicationDelegate.m

```
@synthesize navController;
```

then you can use the following code to get the navController in other classes (Assume your delegate class is `MyApplicationDelegate`):

```
appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UINavigationController *navController = appDeleagte.navController
```

Answer (score 1):

No extra properties needed, available almost anywhere in your application using this macro definition:

```
#define mainNavController (((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).navController)
```

When you put the macro at the top of your source or in a .h header file that you import into your source, then you can start using mainNavController as if it were a local variable.

For example:

```
[mainNavController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Or without the macro, directly in code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.navController; // do something with the navController
```

You can use this code almost anywhere, which is handy if you're working inside a class and you can't access a ViewController directly.

Answer (score -1):

If you are beginer and learner, the navigation controller is shared in whole application which will just prepare the "stack" of your app's viewcontrollers, so you can access the navigationcontroller in any viewcontroller(Only if that controller has been pushed) through out the app. When you push any controller it will added to the "stack" of navigation controller.

You can access the navigation controller with the self object of that viewcontroller itself.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Go through with the link will give complete knowledge of navigation anatomy.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html