# From object to json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

How do I convert a list of objects in JSON ? I searched the internet but all the methods that I used I go wrong. I need to turn the object **coll** into a string json

```
Collections *current = _raccolte[_currentCell];
current.label = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
current.datetime_last_update = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

NSMutableArray *coll = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[coll addObject:current];
HttpClient *client = [[HttpClient alloc] init];
[client syncCollection:coll];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `NSJSONSerialization` class to convert JSON to Foundation objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.

Here you can check it [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html)

```
Collections *current = _raccolte[_currentCell];
current.label = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
current.datetime_last_update = 
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

NSMutableArray *coll = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[coll addObject:current.label];
[coll addObject:current.datetime_last_update];

NSError *writeError = nil; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:coll 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                     error:&writeError];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData 
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", jsonString);
```

Comment: in place of NSArray* coll = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:current.label,current.datetime_last_update]; i have to pass a list of objects, NSMutableArray *coll

Comment: you can also use `NSMutableArray` @FlavioMerolli for just an info i have used `Array` .check my edited answer

Comment: using `NSArray *coll = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:collection];`. collection is NSMutableArray i get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS missing sentinel in method dispatch

Comment: check updated answer @FlavioMerolli

Comment: in NSMutableArray *coll I have a list or items Collection. I have to get a list of jsonObject

Comment: `jsonString` this will gives you that you want

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of questions about json serialization: [iOS JSON serialization for NSObject-based classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515015/ios-json-serialization-for-nsobject-based-classes)

The main idea is to convert your object to `NSDictionary` and then convert it to **jsonData** and (if needed) to string.

In your case you need to create `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` then pass it method like:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                     error:&writeError];
```

Then if you need string you need to make something like:

```
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData 
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to be sure the objects of your collection are serializable. You can achieve this by making your `Collections` object compliant to the `NSCoding` protocol. This requires the implementation of two fundamental methods: `(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` and `void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder`.

Then you can simply use the following handler static method

```
- (NSString*)convertObjectToJson:(NSObject *)object {
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object 
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                         error:&error];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData 
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}
```

This applies for both your own `Collections` instances and the `NSMutableArray`, that is `NSCoding`-compliant by default.