# JSON to NSObject model tool

Tags: objective-c, json, nsobject

I was wondering if there is any tool which you can paste a `JSON` (sample web service response) to generate the `NSObject` data model (create .h .m files as well as defining the properties) automatically.

Let's say you have the following simple JSON:

```
{
  "firstName": "Alex",
  "lastName": "Morgan"
}
```

Use the tool to generate person.h & person.m files like this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@end

@implementation Person
@end
```

Later, just import the files into the project and use them.

Visual Studio has this feature called [Paste Special](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/09/08/Visual-Studio-2013-Paste-Special-JSON-And-Xml/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Serialize/Deserialize complex JSON generically from NSObject class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958883/ios-serialize-deserialize-complex-json-generically-from-nsobject-class)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515015/ios-json-serialization-for-nsobject-based-classes

Comment: @ThomasW The posts don't address the question. I've edited the question more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [JSONExport](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport) a try:

> JSONExport is a desktop application for Mac OS X which enables you to
>   export JSON objects as model classes with their associated
>   constructors, utility methods, setters and getters in your favorite
>   language.

Comment: Exactly what I was talking about. I also found "JSON accelerator" form apple store. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try these Xcode plugins :
 [ESJsonFormat-Xcode](https://github.com/EnjoySR/ESJsonFormat-Xcode) and [XWJsonToCode](https://github.com/boyXiong/XWJsonToCode).

You will need to install the [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/) plugin first though.