# Serialize a custom object as a value using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

So my JSON request should look something like:

```
{ 
   "MyDictionary" : ["some values"], 
   "RegularValue" : "regularValue",
}
```

So what I currently have done is:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"Blah" : @"1", @"Yadayada" : @"2"}; 
NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{"MyDictionary" : myDict, "RegularValue" : "someValue"};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

So this works fine.  The problem I have is, instead of manually creating MyDictionary, what I want to do is use a custom sublcass of NSObject and serialize that to JSON.  I basically have to manually create the NSDictionary for the properties of my custom NSObject and put that in the NSJSONSerialization method.  But I was wondering if there was a better way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help [JLCustomClassDisassembler](https://github.com/joshuaLareta/JLCustomClassDisassembler).

it iterates the custom object to get the properties. this will give you dictionary/array then just use sbjson/jsonkit or what ever you prefer to construct your json string.

Answer (score -3):

To achieve this you would need to create your own custom NSObject class with attributes and more and still have a custom method to serialize the object, similar to the way toString works on java, on Objective-C you would need to implement

```
- (NSString *)description
```

on your method and then return the serialized object.

on this method you could read all the attributes of the current object and then somehow serialize them, this thread presents a nice sample code to read all the attributes of a certain Object

[Get an object properties list in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754824/get-an-object-attributes-list-in-objective-c)