# Object properties to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, uilabel

I have some object with 18 properties (number of properties in that object is static and do not change over the time). Each property stores some information. I need to create a `UILabel`s in cycle (`for`, `foreach`, etc.) and set current `object.property` to current `label`. How I can do that?

Comment: I reading many tutorials with some huge solutions, but not have simple solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the code like that:

```
id object; // your object
NSArray *properties = @[ @"prop1", @"prop2", ... ]; // your properties
[properties enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, idx * 30, 0, 30)]; // or set your custom frame
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object valueForKey:obj]];
    [label sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:label]; // add to some superview
}];
```

You also can get all of your properties using Objective-C Runtime without having prepopulated `properties` array, please refer [here to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754824/get-an-object-properties-list-in-objective-c)

Notice that if some of your properties are scalar types this code will crash. So you probably need some type check here